# Get key values from a nested dictionary

Tags: python, json, python-3.x

I'm trying to write a very simple, yet modular script to rename files.

I would like to process the contents of a JSON file, however, I'm stuck at returning all the sub-values of a key(object?) not just one.

My test code looks like this so far:

```
import json

DB_dict = json.load(open("../source_code/db3.json", encoding='utf-8-sig'))
old_names_of_Book1 = DB_dict["Book1"]["Book1_section1"]["old_name"]
print(old_names_of_Book1)
print("________________________")

for key, values in DB_dict.items():
    print(key)
    print(values)
```

Contents of the imported db3.json:

```
{
  "Book1": {
    "Book1_section1": {
      "old_name": "Adventures of X1",
      "new_name": "Adventures of Y1"
    },
    "Book1_section2": {
      "old_name": "Adventures of X2",
      "new_name": "Adventures of Y2"
    },
    "Book1_section3": {
      "old_name": "Adventures of X3",
      "new_name": "Adventures of Y3"
    },
    "Book1_section4": {
      "old_name": "Adventures of X4",
      "new_name": "Adventures of Y4"
    }
  },
  "Book2": {
    "Book2_section1": {
      "old_name": "Adventures of X1",
      "new_name": "Adventures of Y1"
    },
    "Book2_section2": {
      "old_name": "Adventures of X2",
      "new_name": "Adventures of Y2"
    },
    "Book2_section3": {
      "old_name": "Adventures of X3",
      "new_name": "Adventures of Y3"
    },
    "Book2_section4": {
      "old_name": "Adventures of X4",
      "new_name": "Adventures of Y4"
    }
  }
}
```

The Book1, Book2, Book**x** keys in the JSON file would be hard-coded in the script, as I'd like to rename different files based on the user input using branching statements. For example, if the user picks Book1, then rename each `old_name` value to `new_name`, but don't mind the number of occurrences of "sections".
(The number of sections (`Book1_section1`) could change overtime, therefore, I want my script to iterate on each occurrence of sections.)

My problem is that, I don't know how to ignore the `Book1_section1`, `Book1_section2`, etc... keys in my JSON and only parse their content. With

```
print(DB_dict["Book1"]["Book1_section1"]["old_name"])
```

I can get the value I want but I don't know how to get all the values.

Comment: did you try your_dict.values() ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should try using nested traversal of dict

```
for m,n in DB_dict.items():
    if m == str("Book1"):
        for x,y in n.items():
            print(y["old_name"])
```

Comment: Dumb question:Is `In [13]: ` supposed to be in the code?
Without that, I get the values for each `book`, so I think I'm one stop closer to what I want to achieve. Thank you!

Comment: Your answer greatly helped me to get what I wanted, but it was a solution only to half of my request. However, after playing with conditions, I did get what I wanted, and now I'm in complete control of my code.

If you update your reply with the code below, I would mark your answer as the solution:

`for m,n in DB_dict.items():`
`if m == str("Book1"):`
`for x,y in n.items():`
`print(y["old_name"])`

Thank you very much!

Comment: edited ,hope you have learnt after doing some mental exercise from my half hearted answer,thats my motive was.best of luck